# BottomNavigationView: Change gap size between Title and Icon

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the `BottomNavigationView` height and after change sizes item position won't change.

It's more kinda like the middle gap not changing automatically. however, I want to change this gap size.

> This is `Before` change height and item sizes. These gap sizes are fine with these items but making item smaller it will make a UI issue.
> [image]

> And these one is `After`
> [image]

And this is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    style="@style/MyBottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconSize="20dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Also I'm using `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView ...` if you guys know a better library please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the height of `BottomNavigationView` by overriding the below dimension

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

This will increase/decrease the gap size between icon and text.

Reference: [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/dimens.xml)

Comment: Use `m3_bottom_nav_min_height` if you are using Material 3

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they don't seem to expose that functionality, you can have a look at their [Material Documentation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android) in the *Anatomy and key properties* section.

Answer (score 1):

`app:itemPaddingTop` and `app:itemPaddingBottom` attributes of `BottomNavigationView` can help to adjust the space between the icon and label inside its items.

Actually, these attributes just manage space between the top edge of the view and icon, and then the bottom edge and label respectively but that also makes it possible to increase/decrease space between icon and label.

Comment: Material3 provides a default 'paddingVertical' between icon and label. I have used this solution in Material3. I works as to increase the gap, decrease the padding and to decrease the gap, increase the padding. Happy Coding!